# If-statement confusion

Tags: python

I have a function like the one below. What I try to do is let say I have `checklist('sky high')`, then the output produce will be `30,19` not `0,30,0,19` like what my current code do right now. And if I have `checklist('blue sky')`, the output produce will be `0`. So how can I alter my code?

```
def checklist(argument):

    data = [["sky",'79'],
            ["sky high",'30'],
            ["sky sky",'50'],
            ["sky high",'19']]

    for row in data:
        if argument == row[0]:
           print row[1]

        else:
           print 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def checklist(argument):
    data = [["sky",'79'],
            ["sky high",'30'],
            ["sky sky",'50'],
            ["sky high",'19']]
    #create the list first
    ans = [x[1] for x in data if x[0]==argument]
    #If the list has 0 items then return 0 else return the str.join() version of list
    return ", ".join(ans) if ans else 0

print checklist('sky high')
print checklist('blue sky')
```

**output:**

```
30, 19
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not maintain a `boolean` in case no rows matched your input and check the `boolean` at the end? Which will avoid printing so many 0s.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the extra `0` lines because you `print 0` inside the loop every time an item doesn't match. To avoid this and make the code cleaner, I'd use a slightly different data structure (a dictionary rather than a list of lists). Something like this:

```
def checklist(argument):
    data = {
            "sky":['79'],
            "sky high":['30', '19'],
            "sky sky":['50']
            }
    results = data.get(argument)
    if results is None:
        print 0
    else:
        print('\n'.join(results))

checklist('sblue sky') # prints 0
checklist('sky high') # prints 30\n19
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` statement causes the loop to print `0` if the current element isn't `argument`, which happens quite a lot.

You either have to make a separate list and check outside of the loop:

```
results = []

for row in data:
    if argument == row[0]:
        results.append(row[1])

if results:
    print ','.join(results)
else:
    print 0
```

Or make a dictionary out of your elements:

```
data_dict = {}

for key, value in data:
    if key in data_dict:
        data_dict[key].append(value)
    else:
        data_dict[key] = [value]
```

Now, you can just do this:

```
key = 'sky high'

if key in data_dict:
    print ','.join(data_dict[key])
else:
    print 0
```

Or more concisely:

```
print ','.join(data_dict.get(key, ['0']))
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't want anything to happen if `argument` is not equal to `row[0]`, so just get rid of the else statement.  It's not necessary to specify `else`.

```
def checklist(argument):

    data = [["sky",'79'],
            ["sky high",'30'],
            ["sky sky",'50'],
            ["sky high",'19']]

    for row in data:
        if argument == row[0]:
            print row[1]
```

I misunderstood... Now I see that you want zero if there was never a match.  You could try something like this

```
def checklist(argument):

    data = [["sky",'79'],
            ["sky high",'30'],
            ["sky sky",'50'],
            ["sky high",'19']]
    result = ''
    for row in data:
        if argument == row[0]:
            result += row[0]+','
    if result:
        print result[:-1]  # This slice leaves off the last ','
    else:
        print '0'
```

Note that this will format things a little differently than my first answer.